# imagettfbbox() gives different results on windows annd linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, image, gd

i tried to use the imagettfbbox function to get the width and height for my text. after doing some work everything was fine on my linux machine. when i now run the same script on a windows machine the image looks really bad.

so i made a simple testscript and compared the result:

```
$e = imagettfbbox(12, 0, './Roboto-Regular.ttf', "e");
```

on windows i got

```
Array
(
 [0] => -1
 [1] => -1
 [2] => 8
 [3] => -1
 [4] => 8
 [5] => -10
 [6] => -1
 [7] => -10
)
```

on linux i got

```
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 8
    [5] => -11
    [6] => -1
    [7] => -11
)
```

does anybody know i solution how to get the same values out of this command, maybe with some dirty calculation tricks?

Comment: Try rendering to a larger font size (e.g. 120pt) and then dividing the numbers. That should give you more consistent results. Depending on whether TTF bytecode hinting is turned on, FT can yield different results at small font sizes like 12pt.

Comment: didn't work as expected, with bigger fonts the results are more and more different, with font size 120 on windows the array is [-1,2,70,2,70,-87,-1,-87], on linux [6,2,84,2,84,-88,5,-88]